# How to select child element of sibling in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="participant" id="participant-1">

        <div class="caller">
            <img src="public/img/caller.png" class="img-circle transparent">
        </div>

        <div class="more"><img src="public/img/more.png"></div>


    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to toggle the transparent img class when "more" is clicked.

I have the following code:

```
$(this).siblings(".caller > img.img-circle").toggleClass("transparent");
```

Where am I going wrong? I want to ensure that the toggle only affects the class inside the same parent (HTML is repeated elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going wrong because you seem to be assuming that `.siblings()` will process the selector in some way and traverse down from the generation of `.more` to find the `.img-circle` element. That's not how it works.

`.siblings()` will look for a sibling matching the passed selector; in your case this is `".caller > img.img-circle"`, and the `.more` element doesn't have any siblings matching that. Therefore, your call to `.siblings()` is returning empty.

As others have pointed out, you can use something like:

```
$(this).siblings('.caller').find('.img-circle').toggleClass('transparent');
```

for reference: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.more').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).parent().find('.img-circle').toggleClass("transparent"); 
});
```

Working exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/B2Bcf/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), it gets the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(this).prev().find("img.img-circle").toggleClass("transparent");
```

if you want to use  `.siblings()` then

```
$(this).siblings(".caller").find("img.img-circle").toggleClass("transparent");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 $(this).parent().find(".caller > img.img-circle").toggleClass("transparent");
```

[Live DEmo](http://jsfiddle.net/fLPhv/1/)